# What can you use the iPod 4th generation bluetooth for?

Tags: ipod-touch, bluetooth

I am wondering what I can use the bluetooth capability in the iPod touch fourth generation for? I tried to pair it to a Motorola headset, but I was not able to pair it.

Jailbreaking is not an option for me. :)

Comment: I'm struggling to see what 4th gen iPod has to do with bluetooth usefulness. Each release the capabilities get better and better. It's useful for streaming music, data between devices and accessories like GPS or headphones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The iPod touch 4th gen should allow you to do the following:

[iPhone, iPad, iPod touch: Supported Bluetooth profiles](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3647)
[image: iPod Touch and iPhone Bluetooth Profiles]

With A2DP:
This profile defines how high quality audio (stereo or mono) can be streamed from one device to another over a Bluetooth connection. For example, music can be streamed from a mobile phone, to a wireless headset, hearing aid & cochlear implant streamer, or car audio or from a laptop/desktop to a wireless headset.

With AVRCP:
This profile is designed to provide a standard interface to control TVs, Hi-fi equipment, etc. to allow a single remote control (or other device) to control all of the A/V equipment to which a user has access. It may be used in concert with A2DP or VDP.

With PAN:
This profile is intended to allow the use of Bluetooth Network Encapsulation Protocol on Layer 3 protocols for transport over a Bluetooth link.

With HID:
Provides support for devices such as mice, joysticks, keyboards, as well as sometimes providing support for simple buttons and indicators on other types of devices. It is designed to provide a low latency link, with low power requirements. PlayStation 3 controllers and Wii Remotes also use Bluetooth HID.

-From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile)

If you are having problems pairing, try out [iPhone and iPod touch: Third-party headsets, headphones, and car kits](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1664)

Comment: HFP is what I am looking for, and its crippled by design. I would love to have my Motorola paired with my iPod 4th gen for Skype.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the bluetooth for:

- External keyboard
- Stereo speakers or headphones (Not handsfree headset) for music and audio
- Local multiplayer games with other iOS devices

There are a few other uses, but the above are some of the more common uses for it.

Comment: See its 'headphones' but not 'hands free' which is what my Motorola headset is (mic + mono 1 ear speaker).  I hate having hardware that is crippled by design... *sigh* I would love my headset for Skype.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your responses to the other comments, I realize another potential problem for you.  Skype on mobile devices don't support bluetooth devices.  I'm sorry to be the one to let you know.  It isn't due to the iPod touch or Apple but it's an unsupported feature from Skype.  [Here](https://support.skype.com/en-us/faq/FA10914/What-features-does-Skype-for-iPhone-support?fromSearchFirstPage=false) is the link that shows the list of supported and unsupported features for Skype mobile.